# Unable to make API call using DarkSky API and OKHTTP library

Tags: java, android, api

I am trying to make a simple API call using the OKHTTP library, however my code always goes to the onFailure method. I am not sure why the logcat doesn't display the JSON data when response.body().string() is used. It looks like the code always goes to the onFailure method.

I am also pretty sure that the URL and the access key to the API is correct.

## Main Activity

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.internal.tls.OkHostnameVerifier;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String apiKey = "e614f7a3d13a567393ceed653c28de35";
        double latitude = 37.8267;
        double longitude = -122.4233;

        String forecastURL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + apiKey +
                "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastURL)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.network_unavailable_message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Main UI code is running, hooray!");
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isAvailable = false;

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }

        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

}
```

## Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dhruvmittal.stormy"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1")
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried putting a log in `onFailure` method as well or have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Yes I tried putting in a log in onFailure and it is always running that log in something called a “dead” thread? Not entirely sure what that means

Answer (score 0):

are you set permission on AndroidManifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Yes I have already put internet access in the permissions. It’s still not working.

Comment: after me check with https://www.getpostman.com/ the server result is "Poorly formatted request" check your apikey on darksky

Comment: after i check with https://www.getpostman.com/ the server result is "Poorly formatted request" whit status code 404(page not found),please check your apikey on darksky then edit your apiKey Variable,hope this help

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I have already double checked the API key from darksky. Unfortunately, I still don't get the data. I do get the following error: E/Layer: [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{6b27f44 token=Token{bdb4857 ActivityRecord{e420dd6 u0 com.dhruvmittal.stormy/.MainActivity t81}}})/@0xa2f785d - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found

Comment: After i check https://darksky.net/dev/ i found a requirement for use this library are u have all this required?how if you call other url for test okhttp only, if test success this mean you dont have required for use api from darksky, any way you can use they library at this https://darksky.net/dev/docs/libraries,  hope this help